# Trouble using Lintr in R

Tags: r

This is probably something asinine, but I don't think I've set up `lintr` properly in Rstudio (0.99.486). I have all options in Preferences > Code > Diagnostics and have `lintr` loaded in the project's workspace. However, when I run diagnostics I don't receive errors on syntax, assignment, etc. Is there anything I need to do to enable all the default linters?

(Please disabuse me of whatever dumb mistake I've made thus far.)

```
# Sample code; only warnings are for unknown symbol, unexpected
# tokens, and missing whitespace around binary operator
testing = function(test1, test2)
{
  return paste(test, test1)
}
test.var = 1+2
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. The sample code I provided was there to trigger linting errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think RStudio diagnostics has nothing to do with lintr.

run 
`lint("your-file-to-test.R")`
(or other linters) from the console.

This loads the file into the source pane of RStudio (if it was not already there), runs the test and opens a new tab "Markers" in the console pane with all the warnings concerning your file.

Now you can work on your code quite easily as both panes show the relevant information simultaneously. For a new check, you have to repeat the command from the console. (At least I didn't find a more convenient way of the cycle correcting, testing, correcting.)

Answer (score 0):

The "unexpected symbol" error is the R interpreter's syntax error. The full output which you should have provided is somewhat more informative:

```
> lint('test4.r')
test4.r:3:9: style: Use <-, not =, for assignment.
testing = function(test1, test2)
        ^
test4.r:5:10: error: unexpected symbol
  return paste(test, test1)
         ^
test4.r:8:1: style: Trailing blank lines are superfluous.
```

Comment: I apologise for the confusion—I'm trying to understand Rstudio's own `lintr` integration. Running `lint()` on the file itself behaves perfectly well, it's just that Rstudio isn't displaying the full suite of warnings in its own diagnostics. So am I mistaken in that Rstudio will show all `lintr` warnings as part of its diagnostics, or does `lintr` need to be called explicitly?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the RStudio forum participants.